# How to refer to a variable declared inside a static library?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64, glibc

I am trying to use a modified glibc library. The glibc library is statically linked to my code. I have declared a new variable (lets call it `my_libc_var`) in the glibc library. However, when I try to include that variable in my program (using the `extern` keyword ofcourse), I get `undefined reference` error. How can I solve this problem?

In glibc, the variable is declared as follows.

```
int my_libc_var;
```

whereas, in my program, it is declared as follows.

```
extern int my_libc_var;
```

Comment: Please show us how you declare your variable.

Comment: Edited now to show how it is declared.

Comment: Are you sure you are linking against your modified glibc ? Can you paste compiler results ?

Comment: Please show how you are calling the linker.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether in the compilation process the variable you have added is included in a source file which is compiled using options like `-fvisibility=hidden` or `-fvisibility=internal`. This will make your symbol non-referenceable from other modules.

A similar behaviour, as long as you are using gcc, is obtained using either:

```
#pragma GCC visibility push("hidden")
```

which can be placed at the beginning of the source file, or:

```
int var __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")));
```

in the definition of the symbol (which clearly you didn't place, but I placed it here for completing my answer).

For further information, you can refer to [gcc attribute overview page](http://ohse.de/uwe/articles/gcc-attributes.html#func-visibility).